# Convert a port number to string

Tags: linux, network-programming

I'm trying to convert a port number in integer form to string, to be passed onto getaddrinfo() call. My code for that looks something like this:

```
#define PORT_SIZE 5

void convert(int port) {
   char service[PORT_SIZE+1];
....
....
    memset(service, '\0', PORT_SIZE+1);
    snprintf(service, PORT_SIZE+1, "%d", port);
...
...
}
```

Since the maximum port size on a linux box is 65535, is it correct to have the array size to be five bytes to store the port number?

Thanks!

Comment: why not call `itoa()`?

Comment: I declared the size of 'service' as NI_MAXSERV - a system defined macro. This is probably the right way of doing it.

Comment: Yeah, you can do that. As the manual of `getnameinfo()` says, `NI_MAXSERV` is a guess based on the services listed in the current Assigned Numbers RFC, in order to assist the programmer in choosing reasonable size for the supplied buffer.

Answer (score 1):

It's OK, and if the resulting string is longer than `PORT_SIZE` characters, the remaining characters are discarded and not stored, just counted for the value returned by the function,  so no buffer overflow will occur. And a terminating null character is automatically appended after the content written, so the `memset()` is superfluous.
Or just call `itoa (port, buffer, 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't rely on that kind of limit. Maybe your prog lives 10 years? 20? Runs on amd128? IPV8? How many bits will int have? How many ports will there be then?